# Init javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, date, object

I would like to retrieve a Javascript object Date for new year. I want to user new Date(); object and init it to the 2009-01-01 (it's for a countdown).

Thanks

Comment: For others also looking for documentation on the Javascript Date Object, here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cd9w2te4(v=vs.94).aspx (the link below is broken)

Answer (score 3):

The month part of the construct is an enum, so it's always *themonthyouwant* -1. And are you sure you want to count down to 2009? oh well...

```
var newYears = new Date(2009, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp, you can init your js date object with

```
var date= new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

You may also use date.setFullYear(year,month,day) method if your date object has been created before. Please note that month is between 0 and 11 just like what David Hedlund said.

Answer (score 0):

use...

dateVariable.setTime(Date.parse('1/1/2009 12:00 AM'));